# How can I pass | (pipe) symbol in scenario outline examples

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd

I want to enter a string containing | in a textbox  using scenario outline and examples in selenium-cucumber feature file.
Examples

```
Scenario Outline: test1

> Given user is on home page
> 
> When user enters "<login id>"  and "<password>" and clicks on submit
> button
> 
> Then user is able to login successfully
> 
> Examples:
> 
> |login id | password  |
> 
> | user100 | test|11 |
```

So here I want to send test|11 as password
But when I do so I get compile  error in feature file.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a `|` as part of the cell, you can escape it as `\|`.